# ESPlorer can't communicate with ESP8266

Tags: lua, iot, esp8266, nodemcu, esplorer

I flashed the NodeMCU v0.9.5 to one of my ESP8266 modules. Now I'm trying to send a Lua script to my module using ESPlorer. I already double-checked the wiring.

When I press the "Send to ESP" button, it shows an error:

```
    PORT OPEN 9600

    Communication with MCU...
    ....Got answer! AutoDetect firmware...

    Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received.
    ����,�.,�����(�.,�����Waiting answer from ESP -   Timeout reached. Command aborted.`
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:
After I flashed NodeMCU 1.4 (master) I get a startup message.

```
_flash_used_end:402669c3
fs.start:68000,max:14000
mount res: 0
Task task_lua started.
SIG_LUA received.

NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
    SSL: false
    modules: file,gpio,i2c,net,node,ow,tmr,uart,wifi
build   built on: 2016-02-29 18:25
powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0
lua: cannot open init.lua
> Heap size::42720.
Task task_lua started.
```

When I try to upload a Lua script I get these error messages.

```
fTask task_lua started.
iTask task_lua started.
lTask task_lua started.
eTask task_lua started.
.Task task_lua started.
remove("DS1820.lua");Task task_lua started.
Task task_lua started.
Task task_lua started.
Task task_lua started.
Waiting answer from ESP - Timeout reached. Command aborted.
```

After flashing a new firmeware without debuging mode, I can upload scripts. I'm trying to build this project:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Low-cost-WIFI-temperature-data-logger-based-on-ESP/?ALLSTEPS
But there are no data on Thingspeak. The outputs on the serial line seem to be fine.
I think, everything should be okay?

```
Sending data to thingspeak.com
Got disconnection...
Last temp: 222500
Temp:22.25.2500 C
```

Comment: We must assume the wiring is fine - how else would you have been able to flash the firmware, right? Just as a reminder: GPIO0 must be pulled high or floating for non-flash boot, see http://j.mp/1QnScQo. Did you try with tools other than ESPlorer (see http://j.mp/1TMBqQw for selection)? I doubt it's got anything to do with the problem but _do not_ use those old pre-built binaries. The current master/dev branch are now at 1.4/1.5.1 respectively and anything older is no longer supported. Build the firmware yourself: http://j.mp/1TMBAaC.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! I flashed a new firmware version and now I get something on the serial line. But if I try to flash the firmware I get the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Hhmm, what? "I flashed a new firmware version and now I get something on the serial line" OR "if I try to flash the firmware I get the same error." which one is it, error or not?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. I flashed a new firmware. If I access the ESP8266 now with the ESPlorer, I get a startup message. I can't flash a new LUA script to it.

Comment: Lua scripts are not "flashed" they're "uploaded", it's important to not mix the two. What startup message do you get (update your question)? And what happens if you upload a Lua script?

Comment: I added the error message to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hit on Google for that ESPlorer timeout message is your friend: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/784

I think currently your best bet is to build a firmware with "debug = false", ideally from the `dev` branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now, I can upload something! But I ran into another issue.

Comment: Good, then you should upvote and/or accept this answer and ask a separate question for "another issue" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply clicking on "FS Info" after getting the timeout error worked for me.